# GPIO Connections

Tags: python, rpi.gpio

I would like to use raspberry pi for measurement of Temperature,Humidity,Motion, soil moisture & distance. I would like to add three led indicators. I'll be using following sensors

1) **DHT-11 Digital Temperature & Humidity Sensor** for temperature and humidity measurement

2) **HC-SR501 PYROELECTRIC INFRARED PIR MOTION SENSOR** for motion sensing

3) **Soil Hygrometer Humidity Detection Module Moisture Testing Sensor** for soil moisture

4) **HC-SR04 Ultrasonic Distance Sensor** for measuring distance

5) Three **LED**s as indicators

Is it possible to connect all the sensors at a time ? can i use a single python script to access all these sensors at a time? And what are the precautions to be taken?

p.s:My apologies if i asked anything wrong I'm new here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only questionable item is the soil moisture detector.  It may have an analogue output which is not readable directly by the Pi.  All the Pi's gpios are digital.

```
DHT11 one gpio.
HC-SR501 one gpio.
Soil Hygrometer unknown, do you have a model in mind?
HC-SR04 ranger two gpios.
Three LEDs so three gpios.
```

Yes, you can connect them all at the same time and one Python script would work.

Comment: what about vcc pin of the sensors ? can i connect them in parallel ?

Comment: [link](http://www.ebay.com/itm/1Pcs-New-Soil-Hygrometer-Detection-Moisture-Sensor-Module-for-Arduino-Probe-/271530972307) this soil moisture sensor (this type)

Comment: The moisture sensor digital output is either on or off.  It just reports if a threshold level has been reached (as set by the pot).  If you want more detail you'll need to add an ADC to your set up.  I'd look to be powering everything off 5V if that is possible.  You'll need to check the output levels from the sensors.  If a sensor returns a voltage greater than 3V3 you'll need to include a pair of resistors as a voltage divider.